# A Banach space is reflexive iff its isomorphic image is reflexive.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I am reading Jan van Neerven's *Functional Analysis*, and he proved the following two results. But he

> ***Theorem 4.54.*** A Banach space is reflexive if and only if its closed unit ball is weakly compact.

> ***Corollary 4.55(3).*** If X is isomorphic to a Banach space Y , then X is reflexive if and only if Y is
> reflexive.

The proof to the second result is the standard commutative diagram argument, for example the argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414889/a-space-is-reflexive-if-its-image-under-the-canonical-injection-is-reflexive). He then made a remark.

> Part (3) can be also be deduced from Theorem 4.54; we leave this as an easy exercise.

How can one form an argument in this way?

Answer (score 0):

We show that, if $\phi : X \to Y$ is an isomorphism, then $\phi$ is a weak-to-weak homeomorphism. As $B_Y \subseteq \frac{1}{\|\phi\|}\phi(B_X)$, if $B_X$ is weakly compact, then so is $\phi(B_X)$, and hence $B_Y$, as $B_Y$ is weakly closed and $\phi$ is weak-to-weak continuous. Similarly, $B_X \subseteq \frac{1}{\|\phi^{-1}\|}\phi^{-1}(B_Y)$, so if $B_Y$ is weakly compact, then so is $B_X$. We just need to show $\phi$ is a weak-to-weak homeomorphism.

For any subbasic open set $f^{-1} U \subseteq Y$, where $U \subseteq \Bbb{F}$ is open and $f \in Y^*$, we can write:
$$\phi^{-1}(f^{-1}U) = (f \circ \phi)^{-1}U,$$
which is weakly open in $X$. Thus $\phi$ is weak-to-weak continuous. A symmetric argument on $(\phi^{-1})^*$  shows $\phi^{-1}$ is weak-to-weak continuous. Thus, it is a homeomorphism as expected.